# Consolidate JSON array in PHP from MySQL Query Results

Tags: php, mysql, json

The existing code looks like this:

```
function getList(){
 
   $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT `person`.`person_name` as name, `skill`.`skill_name` as 
   skill,`skill_linker`.`skill_score`;
       
   $result = $GLOBALS['conn']->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $emptyArray = array();
 
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $emptyArray[] = $row;
  }
  echo json_encode($emptyArray);
 } 
}
```

JSON Output from above function:

```
[{
"name":"Bob Sun",
"skill":"Dancing",
"skill_score":"3"
},

{
"name":"Bob Sun",
"skill":"Surfing",
"skill_score":"2"
},

{
"name":"Bob Sun",
"skill":"Swimming",
"skill_score":"5"
},

{
"name":"Joe Steel",
"skill":"Eating",
"skill_score":"2"
},
{
"name":"Joe Steel",
"skill":"Cooking",
"skill_score":"3"
}]
```

Instead, I would like the JSON output to look something like this:

```
[
      {
        "name": "Bob Sun",
        "skills" : [
            "Dancing": 3,
            "Surfing": 2,
            "Swimming": 5
        ]
      },
    
      {
        "name": "Joe Steel",
        "skills" : [
            "Eating": 2,
            "Cooking": 3
        ]
      }
]
```

Can this be done? How can I have it display skills:skill_score for each person if the data coming from the SQL result set is separate? How can I change the code to restructure the JSON data to have semi-categories?

Answer (score 0):

Just transform the array in your while cycle.

```
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $emptyArray[$row['name']]['name'] = $row['name'];
    $emptyArray[$row['name']]['skills'][$row['skill']] = $row['skill_score'];
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

insted of applying `json_encode` on the final array ,

- apply it on row
- concatinate all rows
- inset final concatinated string into array

this may solve the issue

Comment: This answer has multiple issues. 1. Encoding each row separately and do string concatenation is very unnecessary (and error prone) when they can simply create an array in the format they want and run one single json_encode in the end (which is the recommended way). 2. This doesn't answer their actual question, which wasn't about how to json_encode the data bur rather how to get the specific _format_ they showed. Also, an answer should contain a proper example, not just high-level points what they should do (without any further explanation)